# Is there a way to find the type of a template (generic) parameter in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to do something like this in Java:

```
public static <T> T foo() {
  return (T) bar(T);
}

public static Object bar(Class<?> klaz) {
  return klaz.newInstance();
}
```

But the code doesn't compile since I can't substitute *T* for a *Class<?>*.
With a concrete class, I can call *bar* like:

```
bar(ConcreteClass.class);
```

But the same does not work for *T*. i.e. there's no such thing as *T.class*

In C#, *typeof* works for both concrete and template types. So, the call to bar would've been:

```
bar(typeof(T));
```

But I haven't been able to find anything similar in Java.

Am I missing something, or does Java not have a way of getting the type of a template parameter? And if Java doesn't have the facility, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no way to get the type. Java's generics use type erasure so even java itself does not know what T is at runtime.

As for workarounds: you could define foo to take a parameter of type `Class<T>` and then use that.