# How to get type of generic

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the class of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)
>   [How to obtain class instance generic argument type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372432/how-to-obtain-class-instance-generic-argument-type)

I have some c# code:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{ 

   private static Dictionary<Type, Type> services = new Dictionary<Type, Type>();

   public static void RegisterService<T>(Type service)
   {
      services[typeof (T)] = service;
   } 

...

}
```

I want to write the same logic on java. How can I get type of generic T (T.getClass() not working)
like `typeof (T)` in c#?

Comment: Duplicate of any of several: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353901/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-type-of-a-template-generic-parameter-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372432/how-to-obtain-class-instance-generic-argument-type, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Generics are [erased after compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). You have to pass `Class<T>` as argument.

I don't quite understand your example, though. Why would you want to map a `Type` (`Class`) to itself?

Comment: As you can use as "service" a subclass of Type, the result would be different.

Comment: It's something like IoC Container which registers one type for another and can be retrieved by registered key.

Comment: No itself , I wont write something like ServiceLocator.RegisterService<IReportBuilder>(typeof(ReportBuilder)) and after call ServiceLocator.Resolve<IReportSender>() that will return instance of  ReportBuilder

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable, But you can check isAssignableFrom(Class cls) for all the Classes you expect it to be, but It's sounds like a better design can be implemented here (one that doesn't involve type checking)