# java - How to get the type of the parameter from a parameterized argument

Tags: java, generics

I'm having troubles trying to find a solution, if any, to this:

```
public class Generics {
    Map<Class<? extends SomeObject1>, SomeObject2>> map;
    map = new HashMap<Class<? extends SomeObject1>, SomeObject2>>();

    public static <E extends SomeObject1> SomeObject2 get(Class<E> c) {
        if (map.containsKey(c))
           return map.get(c);
        else {
           SomeObject2 o = new SomeObject2();
           map.put(c, o);
           return o;
        }
    }
}
...
//somewhere
public <T extends SomeObject1> void aMethod(AnInterestedClass<T> list) {
    // How to get the value from the map
    // knowing that the key is of type T?
    Generics.get(); 
}
```

Ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353901/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-type-of-a-template-generic-parameter-in-java

Comment: @jalopaba, I don't think it's a duplicate. Actually I'm using this mapping without any problem: ´Generics.get(SomeObject1.class);´. The question arises as a new need I have in the project (the ´aMethod()´ example). Evidently, the codeMangle question was somekind misleading with its needs and solution. The answer is what relates this question though. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you can only do this by passing a Class object to `aMethod`. See [this related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416540/java-map-with-values-limited-by-keys-type-parameter?rq=1).

Comment: I had previosly read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type) trying to find a solution to the problem. But reading your comment makes me search a different approach. Thanks.